# Authenticated requests to web server from client logged in with Supabase

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

In my case, I have a web client, a web server and a desktop app.
First the user creates a profile in the web client with email and password. At this point, once it's in the homepage, the user connects 3rd party services using OAuth2.0. The server handles the Authorization code flow and needs to store `access_token` and `refresh_token` somewhere.

So, the first problem is how do I store things in Supabase Postgres DB from the server?

Can I just access it using any library that connects to an SQL db following details [here](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/connecting-to-postgres)?

Assuming this is done, now the user will download the desktop app and login using the same username and password. Supabase on the client is happy and the user is authenticated. Now I need to request to my web server some resources.

Second problem is, how do I prove to the server that I am user X?

Edit: From [here](https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions/6723) seems like I need to pass the JWT to the server and authenticate it using supabase library.

Answer (score 2):

You can store information into Supabase Postgres database using any server side library that can connect to Postgres. You can find your connection information for the database by going to the [Settings > Database](https://app.supabase.com/project/_/settings/database) section then scrolling down to Connection string and selecting the language tab to get the information.

You can prove that you are user X by sending the JWT to the server and then authenticating with it using the supabase library.

If you are using the supabase-js v1 library you would use the setAuth method:

```
supabase.auth.setAuth(jwt)
```

If you are using supabase-js v2 library you would create a new connection and pass the JWT to that:

```
const serverSupabase = createClient(SUPABASE_URL, SUPABASE_ANON_KEY, { 
  global: { 
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}` }
  }
})
```